# sqlite jdbc setJournalMode

Tags: sqlite, jdbc

I running my first trials on SQLite (with JDBC) as pure memory database. As I need very fast inserts I tried to set the config accordingly. I could find out that the code below fails only at the setting for JournalMode. Please refer to the method shown below. The variables con and isConnected are defined as class vars and not shown here.

Thanks a lot

Rolf

```
public Boolean connect() {
    try {
         Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");      // sqlitejdbc_3.7.2
        // Set all pragmas
         SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();

         // This statement (JournalMode setting) causes a fail
         // Without that statement the connection can be established
         // ==> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: batch entry 0: query returns results
         config.setJournalMode(JournalMode.MEMORY);  

         config.setTempStore(TempStore.MEMORY);
         config.setSynchronous(SynchronousMode.OFF);
         config.enforceForeignKeys(false);
         config.enableCountChanges(false);

         con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::memory:", config.toProperties()); 

         isConnected = true ;
         return  true ;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        LogMessages.instance().print(0, LogMessages.MSG_SEVERITY.ERROR, e.getMessage() + "\n");
        e.printStackTrace() ;
        return false ;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but there is an other way to disable it. After opening the connection you can execute this query : 
PRAGMA journal_mode=MEMORY;